# Eclipse Java Console Application Isn't Showing

Tags: java, eclipse, window, console-application

So, I am new to Java, e.g I started a few hours ago. So I'm working with Eclipse, and I exported a Hello World program as an executable jar file, and so when I double click on my application, it loads for a quick second, and then nothing happens.

Here's the code that I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

However, when I make Java open a window with the following code, it actually opens the window. Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setSize(400, 400);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setResizable(true);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;
    }
}
```

Why won't the code in the first example open?

Comment: try running your application from a command window/console

Comment: @JohnKane Nope, it didn't work.

Comment: were there any errors that it listed?

Comment: @JohnKane No, the program runs completely fine inside of Eclipse, and in the command prompt it didn't show any errors or text.

Comment: I meant when you tried to run it from the console/command window outside of eclipse

Comment: for example  java -jar myjarfile.jar

Comment: @JohnKane Running it like that in the command prompt worked for me! That still doesn't answer the question though, as that's not done by opening the file itself.

Comment: when you click on a jar to execute it it will run you just will not be able to see the output unless you use some gui. I am not sure why though, it could be that it just runs quickly and you do not see the output. In this case without loading a console there is no way to enter any input so maybe the scanner just skips nextline call. This is just a guess though

Comment: @JohnKane How can I make a console gui then to show the result?

Comment: you would need to learn swing or javafx, and you would not be using a scanner class. This is more advanced. if you are just starting I would stick to something more basic. GUI programming is a lot more complicated than running something from a console

Comment: @JohnKane All I'm trying to do is run something from a console!

Comment: yes and to do that you need to use a console ie windows cmd or a linux shell

Answer (score 0):

I just found that this defeats the purpose of WORA, because opening a command window automatically will differ between operating systems.

Comment: The thing is, the user can open the console and call the Jar directly. This is not a problem with WORA. Executable Jars were more intended for apps. with GUIs.